# Flash AS2 equivalent

Tags: java, flash, actionscript-2

I have developed a program in flash and Action Script 2. Its an offline program. Basically it has options like, index page which links to the relevant pages, search option in each page through which we can jump from any page to any page, playing videos, audios and showing images by clicking a button, timer based puzzles, storing and retrieving text data etc. Now I would like to do the same in some other programming language. I prefer core java. Will it be tedious? Because in flash GUI is already there but in java it has to be created as well. I am very particular about offline program. Any suggestions please?

Comment: ActionScript3, AIR. First, you are familiar with Flash and migrating to AS3 is not so bad, second, AS3 is much faster than AS2, tens or even hundreds times faster, and AIR allows you to publish for many target platforms, starting with Windows Desktop and Android.

Comment: Hey, Thanks. I already started converting my project in flash AS3. But it won't support Linux. That is why I thought of doing it in Java.

Comment: Weeeell, it's AIR 2.6 I think that was the last Linux build. I know it's a handicap yet a lot of functionality is still available.